# qt creator editing missing some characters (blank) Linux

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator

Im running a fedora 18 box and just installed Qt Creator 3.0,
as well as trying 2.8.1.  Both versions, when I pull up my source
code, there are many characters missing in patterns.  It looks like
15-25% of the code has sections "missing"

I think its a graphics problem maybe, but I can find no articles online
about this issue so far.  Anyone know what this is or how to fix it?

Thanks

EDIT: Here's the image.  Also using vim they look fine.  Im compiling and running
from an xterm window due to qcreator's issue (unfortunately).  if I 'file' the source
files, they are: C source, ASCII text

[image: qcreator 2.8.1 example .cpp]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot to demonstrate what you mean? Are you sure the characters are only "missing" in QtCreator, i.e. have you checked in another environment? Also, can you share the repository url so that we can also try on our end?

Comment: You forgot to mention the repository URL in the update! Also, what happens if you select all? Does something get visible?

Comment: Sorry, forgot.  There is no repo url.  Yes, when I select all things appear.  It definitely seems to be refresh/video related.  I saw this issue last year on an Ubuntu system as well, so I was surprised not to find any articles on it online yet.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Does it also happen with other codebases or particularly with this one? Was it the same codebase on your Ubuntu?

Comment: Different code bases do this.  Ive seen at least 3 different code bases do this.  Im very surprised nobody else (thus far that I can find) has seen this, especially since I first saw it last year across multiple qt creator versions and different computers.

Comment: Just installed a new Ubuntu 12.04 LTS last week and its also doing the same thing with Creator 3.0.0.  Cant believe nobody else has seen this.